# To test 500.html in Django dev, localhost environment

Tags: django, debugging, http-status-code-500

I am customizing 500.html and set Debug to False, so it renders 500 error but as Debug is set to False, it cannot render the static files correctly.

How can I set it to the production mode and test the 500 error page correctly? or how can I set static files correctly when debug is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`--insecure`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver-insecure) flag to force serve the static files

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thx.